# VSCode: Unwanted autocompletion of C++ keywords in Visual Studio Code

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

I have been using visual studio code for a while and noticed that it has some unwanted autocomplete suggestions.

My installed C++ plugins:

```
C/C++
C/C++ Advanced Lint 
C/C++ Snippets
C++ Algorithm Mnemonics
C/C++ Clang Command Adapter
```

My problem:

Whenever I type and hit enter:  `public:`
It expands to:    `public:ARG_MAX`.

I either have to hit escape before enter, or delete the word `ARG_MAX` all the times. Is there a better way to stop or not use this auto expansion for the keyword "public" ?

[image]

Comment: Maybe switching accept suggestions on enter off? (`ctrl+comma`; then type `enter`; then switch accept suggestions on enter off.)

Answer (score 0):

this may be a actual bug in vscode you may want to look at issues on vscode's githun but i remember